# Farkas' Lemma and Theorem of Alternatives

Tags: geometry, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, dual-cone

Let's define the DUAL CONE of a subset Y of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as follows: $$Y^*=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \langle x,y\rangle \ge 0\quad\forall y\in Y\}.$$ If $Y$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. if there are $v_1,\dots,v_m\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $Y=\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$, then I will write $(v_1,\dots,v_m)^*$ to denote the dual cone of $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$.

Now I'd like to prove that $((v_1,\dots,v_m)^*)^*=\{\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\mid \lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\quad\forall i=1,\dots, m\}$ by using Theorem of Alternatives. The set on the right hand side of the equality is called the CONVEX CONIC HULL of $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ and it is the set of all conic combinations (linear combinations with nonnegative scalars) of the vectors $v_1,\dots, v_m$.

### Theorem of Alternatives

The Theorem of Alternatives states the following:

> Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix, $B$ a $p\times n$ matrix, $C$ a $q\times n$-matrix with $A\ne 0$. Let's consider the system
> $$S_1:\; \begin{cases}
> Ax<0\\
> Bx\le 0\\
> Cx=0
> \end{cases}$$
> The system $S_1$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ IF AND ONLY IF $\exists \theta\in(\mathbb{R}^\ge)^m, \lambda\in(\mathbb{R}^\ge)^p,\mu\in\mathbb{R}^q$ such that $A^T\theta+B^T\lambda+C^T\mu=0\quad$ (system $S_2$).

My idea is to consider the matrix $M$ having as rows the vectors $v_1,\dots, v_m$ and to notice that $(v_1,\dots,v_m)^*=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid Mx\ge 0\}$ but I don't know how to continue. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Is youe question about proving Farkas?

Comment: If $y=(y_1,\dots, y_k)$ is  a vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$ I write $y\ge 0$ to say $\begin{cases} y_1\ge 0\\ \vdots \\ y_k\ge 0\end{cases}$.

Comment: Right. That one is the usual euclidean product in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yes, it is. I know that it's called Farkas Lemma the special case $n=1$ and $C=0$ of the theorem of alternatives

Comment: @MishaLavrov You are right, I forgot another * in the problem. I corrected it

Comment: The identity $\ \big(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\big)^*=\big\{\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\,\big| 
\,\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\ \forall i=1,\dots, m\big\}^*\ $ is relatively trivial, and you don't need the theorem of alternatives to prove it. You *would* need it (or an equivalent), however, if you wanted to prove$$
\big(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\big)^{**}=\big\{\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\,\big| 
\,\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\ \forall i=1,\dots, m\big\}\ .
$$
Is it this latter identity, rather than the former, that you want to prove?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes, you are right! My idea in order to prove the second identity that you wrote is to use the Bidual Theorem that says that if $C$ is closed convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $(C^*)^*=C$. Now I'd like to prove that the set on the right hand side is closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the fact that it is a convex cone is clear).

Comment: Your idea of appealing to the theorem of alternatives can get you
$$
\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,Mx\ge0\,\big\}^*=\big\{\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\,\big| 
\,\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\ \forall i=1,\dots, m\big\}\ .
$$
I'll write up an outline as an answer.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Ok thank you, I look forward to your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your reply to my comment, I gather that the result you're looking for is
$$
\big(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\big)^{**}=\big\{\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\,\big| 
\,\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\ \forall i=1,\dots, m\big\}\ ,
$$
or, equivalently, since you've already shown that $\ \big(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\big)^*=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,Mx\ge0\,\big\}\ $,
$$
\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,Mx\ge0\,\big\}^*=\big\{\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\,\big| 
\,\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\ \forall i=1,\dots, m\big\}\ .
$$
If $\ y\in\big\{\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\,\big| 
\,\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\ \forall i=1,\dots, m\big\}\ $, then $\ y^T=\lambda^TM\ $ for some $\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}^m\ $ with $\ \lambda\ge0\ $. So if $\ x\ $ is any vector in $\ \big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,Mx\ge0\,\big\}\ $, then $\ \langle y,x\rangle=\lambda^TMx\ge0\ $ because both $\ \lambda\ge0\ $ and $\ Mx\ge0\ $. Therefore $\ y\in$$\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,Mx\ge0\,\big\}^* $, and it follows that
$$
\big\{\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\,\big| 
\,\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^\ge\ \forall i=1,\dots, m\big\}\subseteq\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,Mx\ge0\,\big\}^*
$$
Now let $\ a\in\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\big|\,Mx\ge0\,\big\}^*\ $. Then for every $\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ $ with $\ Mx\ge0\ $ we must have $\ 0\le\langle a,x\rangle=a^Tx\ $. This means that the system of inequalities
\begin{align}
a^Tx&<0\\
Mx&\ge0
\end{align}
can have no solution.  Can you finish it off from here?  I think the easiest way is to appeal to the form of [Farkas's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) as it's given in Wikipedia.  In this connection, there appears to be something missing from the system $\big(S_2\big)$  as given in your statement of the theorem of alternatives (I'm guessing that $\ \theta\ $ should be required to be non-zero).  As given, the system $\big(S_2\big)$ *always* has the solution $\ \theta=0, \lambda=0, \mu=0\ $.

Comment: Ok PERFECT! Now everything is clear. Thank you very much